# Bootstrap panels side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, panels

Someone knows why my panels are not in one row? I want them side by side not like:

```
PANEL
PANEL
PANEL
```

I need this:

```
PANEL | PANEL | PANEL
```

I'm creating offer panels from mysql.

And i need all offer in one row.

my code:

http://hastebin.com/inukiyumob.xml

I tried many options from google, any doesnt work or im really idiot. ofc i'm...

I did too many options, any doesnt work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should endure your `div` with class `.row` beyond cycle '`while`'. And leave only div with class `col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5` inside cycle.
And for each iteration you will get new `panel` in one row.

Comment: ah it works but watch that awful distance between panels: http://scr.hu/9a5/7eknx

Comment: I can't see any of bootstrap's class, and i see it's just image http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/sc/96/ou/mv0e5o.jpg

Comment: screen what i send shows how its look after adding your code.

Comment: i think problem is your panel width less than widht of .col-lg-5, try to change to .col-lg-2 or .col-lg-3, something like this.

Comment: how can i make to all panels be in 2 rows? i have that bug: http://scr.hu/9a5/mcznb
 code: http://hastebin.com/ihasotabat.xml

Comment: i dont want that empty field

Comment: It's hard to say just looking at the picture, I would like to see rendering html through firebug.

Comment: I found out, just add div with class col-lg-12 under div with class .row, but not in the cycle 'while'.

Comment: can you send me an example?

Comment: edit my code and send me please, im doing something bad

Comment: try like this: http://hastebin.com/kahodobugu.xml, i think it should work. Take a look at bootstrap grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/, take a look how it works, it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem, but didn't want to fix the width of my panels to a specific percentage. I wanted them to flow based on their content width.

I already had a container div wrapped around my column divs. All it took was to apply a little CSS ...

```css
.admin > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Here is the HTML ..

```html
<div class="admin">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working nicely for me, with each panel only being as wide as it needs to be.